# I need to create a class diagram for a program I am working on

Tags: class, uml, diagram

Hi I am writing a HTML Generator for a project in college, the program will be written in java and will allow a user to set a header, create paragraphs, add images to the page, add a coloured background, set a footer and create a contact form. I have started modelling in with StarUML but it is not my strongest subject.

What I have come up with so far is the following..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ed0aI.jpg

For all I know, this is 100 percetn wrong. Would anyone care to help me understand UML a little more and send me in the right direction? I can provide more information on my project if necessary, I have a feasibility study done for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first lets ask the "**Question Zero**":

> Why you draw UML class diagram?

It seems that you are at starting of new project. So you may use  UML class diagram for:

- To discover your candiate classes for your design
- To evaluate alternative designs

In that case it is better to work static and dynamic behaviour of your object oriented design at the same time.

> Since you do not work with dynamic part, your classes in Class
>   Diagrams seems to isolated, does not have any relation ship between them.[ even structural ]
>   But in a true object oriented system, a task of system is done with
>   the Collaborations of objects .

So forget any UML modeling tool at first... Find two big papers or wall surfaces...

- Ask yourself what the system will-should do? Lists taks that system
  will do
- Then find-list your candiate objects which will be responsible for those tasks...Draw them on a Class Diagram...
- Then draw **Communication Diagram or Sequence Diagrams** on second
  surface-paper which shows how those objects will  collaborat to
  achive their task.
- Do those in parallel...While you draw Communication Diagram or
  Sequence Diagrams you may discover newclasses ... or new  methods for
  classes ... Note them on ClassDiagram.

If those activities does not any value, not help you produce quality code ask the Question zero again in a different way...

> Does drawing  UML diagram add any value to my coding-design?

**If your answer is No, forget drawing any diagram.**

To get a big picture about UML, Check [What UML Is and Isn't by Craig Larman](http://blog.csdn.net/chiefsailor/article/details/1401412)

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help you understand how the class diagrams work, and their relationships:

https://creately.com/blog/diagrams/class-diagram-relationships/

Although this is not a programming question...

Answer (score 0):

I dont find anything wrong in diagram you have posted.
Just you have to keep in mind that number of classes that you are displaying in `class diagram` should be equal to number of `.java` file in your project and carefully add attributes and operation in each class. and go through different types of `relationship` that are used in class diagram.  `Relationship` is very important to understand the flow when you draw class diagram.

adn atleast study this two links [Class diagram basics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram)
and [Purpose of class diagram](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/uml/uml_class_diagram.htm)

And go through some example of class diagram available on net for practice will help you a lot